# How to proof by contradiction that for all $m ,n >0$: $m+n \ge 2 \sqrt{mn}$

Tags: inequality

I struggled with what kind of proof to go for:

To proof: for all $m$ and $n$: $m+n \not\ge 2 \sqrt{mn}$

or to proof for all $m$ and $n$: $m+n \le 2 \sqrt{mn}$

Either way i also didnt know how to continue

Comment: what values do $m$ and $n$ take?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh all positive integers

Comment: Are these inequalities the right way round?

Comment: @LordShark: I wonder the same thing.

Comment: They way I see it you don't need a prove it by contradiction. Just square both sides and end up with an equivalent inequality whose veracity you can easily prove.

Comment: nope: https://imgur.com/OxHU2l8

Comment: So "nope" = "yep"? $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** try squaring both sides of the inequality.

Comment: we get $m^2 + 2mn + n^2 \ge 4mn$

Comment: Which gives us -2mn on one side with m squared and n squared an 0 on the other. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

squaring the inequality we have
$$m^2+n^2+2mn\geq 4mn$$
this is $$(m-n)^2\geq 0$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Your $(m-n)^2\ge 0$ would also hold for $m=n=-1$ even though the original inequality would then be false, so be careful

Comment: i don't understand, the Problem stated $$m,n>0$$

Comment: and also we can not square $$m+n$$ if $$m+n<0$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that is not true, then there exists positive integers $m,n$ such that $m+n < 2\sqrt{mn}$

Since both sides of the inequality are positive, we can square them and preserve the inequality sign.

$$m^2+2mn+n^2 < 4mn$$

Try to rearrange the inequality and factorize things.

Remark: $$\neg [\forall x \in A, P(x)] \equiv [ \color{blue}{\exists} x \in A, \neg P(x)]$$

Comment: do you mean $\le $ or $\lt$?

Comment: $\geq$ means greater or equal to. If that is not true, you get less than $<$.

Comment: Oh okay, Thanks!

Comment: And the remark also cleared some stuff up. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this will hold for only **non - negative** values of $m$ and $n$.

If you take both negative, say, $m = -1$ and $n = -4$, we have $m + n = -5 < 2\sqrt{-1 \times -4} = 4$. Therefore, for both negative, your inequality does not hold. Also, for one positive other negative we end up with imaginary numbers. So, I will, in this answer, go only for positive values of $m$ and $n$ and try to prove the given statement with proof by contradiction.

Since you want to go with proof by "contradiction", assume that the given hypothesis is wrong.

$$\therefore \exists m, n \ge 0 \left( m + n < 2 \sqrt{mn} \right)$$

We start with this and will try to end up with a contradiction.

Given that

$$m + n < 2 \sqrt{mn}$$

$$\therefore m^2 + 2mn + n^2 < 4mn$$

$$\therefore m^2 - 2mn + n^2 < 0$$

$$\therefore \left( m - n \right)^2 < 0$$

Since $m$ and $n$ are real numbers, $m - n$ is also a real number and hence its square must be non - negative. Thus, we et a contradiction and we may conclude that our assumption was wrong.

$$\therefore \forall m, n \ge 0 \left( m + n \ge 2 \sqrt{mn} \right)$$

Comment: Thanks dude! Using characters with the there exists instead of for all helped me understand it more than i did before!

Answer (score 0):

especially a proof by contradiction was being asked for. So I guess it's rather the method  that counts than the result (which is well known).

So suppose the opposite, i.e. $m+n < 2 \sqrt{mn}$. Then you have

$m+n - 2 \sqrt{mn} < 0$ or

$\sqrt{m}^2 + \sqrt{n}^2 - 2 \sqrt{mn} < 0$ which is

$(\sqrt{m} -  \sqrt{n} )^2  < 0$

Now the left hand side is obviously not negative since it is a square.  So there is your contradiction.

Hence you have shown $m+n \ge 2 \sqrt{mn}$.